# Perform accent insensitive fulltext search MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, full-text-search, diacritics

I'm currently developing a search functionality for a website. Users search for other users by name. I'm having some trouble getting good results for users that have accents on their name.

I have a FULLTEXT index on the name column and the table's collation is utf8_general_ci.

Currently if somebody registers for the site, and has a name with accents (for example: Alberto Andrés), the name is stored in the DB as shown in the following image:

[image: Alberto AndrÃ©s]

So if I perform the following query `SELECT * MATCH(name) AGAINST('alberto andres')` I get lots of results with better match scores like 'Alberto', 'Andres', 'Andrés' and finally with a low match score the record the user is probably looking for 'Alberto Andrés'.

What could I do to take into account the way accented records are currently stored in the DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the surname of el Señor Andrés is actually stored correctly.  The rendering you showed us is the way some non-UTF apps mangle UTF8 text.

You might try this modification of your query if you don't yet have a whole bunch of records in your table.  Fulltext (non-boolean) mode works weirdly on small data sets.

```
SELECT *  
  FROM TABLE
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('alberto andres' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

You also might try

```
SELECT *  
  FROM TABLE
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST(CONVERT('alberto andres' USING utf8))
```

just to make sure your match string is in the same character set as your MySQL columns.

Comment: Thanks Ollie for your answer! Boolean mode doesn't improve the results. And 'using utf8' returns the same records. Interestingly if I do utf8_encode('Alberto Andrés') on php and pass the output to the query, I do get Alberto Andrés as the first result. I still haven't figured it out the solution for when the user enters the name without accents to the search query.

Comment: I know it' s a bit late, but neither of these improve my search. I have situation where user can enter "Z, C, S, D", but DB has to return results that contain "Ž,Š, Č, Ć and Đ." Searching the web whole morning no result :D.